# og:image taken from tumblr page content

Tags: html, metadata, facebook-opengraph, tumblr

I am developing a [tumblr site](http://thejoysofcode.tumblr.com/) for programming jokes.

On this site I am using the following Facebook OpenGraph metadata to generate the thumbnail for a post when it is Liked:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-128}"/>
```

This specifies the tumblr page icon at size 128x128. What I would like is to parse the page and generate the icon dynamically by picking the image in each post. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it for sure if you're on the Permalink page by doing this:

```
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Posts}
    {block:Photo}
    <meta property="og:image" content="{PhotoURL-500}">
    {/block:Photo}
{/block:Posts}{/block:PermalinkPage}
```